# Use requests to bulk query online calculator

Tags: python, webforms, python-requests

I am trying to write some python code to automate the querying of an online medical calculation tool. The ressource is available at:
http://www.shef.ac.uk/FRAX/tool.aspx?lang=en

I am new to this type of thing, but understand from my research that I should be able to use the python requests package for this.
From my inspection of the page source I have identified the form element

```
<form method="post" action="tool.aspx?lang=en" id="form1">
```

And the elements that seem to directly correspond to the fields (eg. age) look like this

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$toolage" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_toolage" maxlength="5" size="3" onkeypress="numericValidate(event)" style="width:40px;" />
```

My testing code so far looks like this (The only required fields to have filled out are age, sex, weight and height):

```
import requests
url="http://www.shef.ac.uk/FRAX/tool.aspx?lang=en"
payload ={'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$toolage':'60',
      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$year':'1954',
      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$month':'01',
      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$day':'01',
      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$sex':'female',
      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$weight':'70',
      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ht':'165',

      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$facture':'no',
      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1facture_hip$':'no',
      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$smoking':'no',
      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$glu':'no',
      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rhe_art':'no',

      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$sec_ost':'no',
      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$alcohol':'no',
      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$bmd_input':'',
      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnCalculate':'Calculate',
      }

req = requests.post(url, params=payload)
with open("requests_results.html", "w") as f:
f.write(req.content)
```

This however does not work. I don't get en error message but the resulting saved html page (which I would later parse for the results) contains just the initial page with no resulting values. In addition to the fields in my current payload the form also contain other elements that are perhaps necessary, such as hidden elements for some of the same data types like age

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$toolagehidden" type="hidden" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_toolagehidden"
```

I have tried different combinations of payloads, but the results are the same. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You want to encode the payload before the POST. Like this:

```
import urllib

usefulpayload = urllib.urlencode(payload)
```

Then use `usefulpayload` in your request.

Comment: Ok I tried submitting the current payload in urlencoded form, but it does not make a difference. What problem is the encoding supposed to solve?